# What is the difference between os.read() and sys.stdin.read() in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, io, built-in

In the link given below, the answers suggests that both `os.read()`/`os.write()` and `sys.stdin.read()`/`sys.stdout.write()` can be used for fast I/O. But I didn't find any explanation regarding which among the two is faster or is there any specific case where one performs better than other.

Can someone please explain the difference between these methods?

[Fastest stdin/out IO in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982146/fastest-stdin-out-io-in-python-3)

Comment: If you want to know which is fastest, you'll have to profile it on your own machine.

Comment: Other than performance, there isn't any other difference?

Comment: Well certainly `os.read()` is less commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should measure to check, but `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` are [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) objects that, at a minimum, include the additional functionality of decoding incoming data to unicode, and encoding outgoing data to whatever encoding is configured for the output stream.

On that basis it should be the case that `os.read()/os.write()` will be faster as these are lower level functions that deal only with bytes, regardless of encoding, if you are dealing with byte oriented data e.g. ascii text, binary etc.

If you are profiling the `os` functions you should also take into account the time to separately encode and decode the data if that is required by your application. You might find that performing encoding and I/O in two separate steps will be slower than the `sys` methods.

Some other differences in Python 3 are that the `os` functions accept/return `bytes` objects whereas the `sys` objects deal with `str` objects.

Comment: could you perhpas advise with an `os.write` [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502211/printing-a-font-icon-with-os-write)?