# Printing a font icon with os.write

Tags: python-3.x, stdout

With Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10, my terminal, Set with a [nerdfont](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Agave) that has icons, shows the thumbs up icon for:

```
import os, sys     # For the following attempts

print('\uf164')
```

I also get a thumbs up via:

`sys.stdout.write('\uf164')`

However, for:

`os.write(1, '\uf164'.encode('utf8'))`

I get 3 characters, one for each encoded byte.

How do I print the thumbs up using `os.write`?

Comment: Is the problem you are getting `3` as bytes written or you can't see thumbs up properly? In my machine, it prints thumbs up just like `sys.stdout.write` did and `3` is returned.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting 3 weird characters and `3` is returned, don't see the thumbs up

Comment: Do you really have a Unicode-native terminal? I finally pulled up a Windows machine to reproduce this on, and it reports that it natively uses CP437, not UTF-8.

Comment: I was actually using ConEmu. It seems `cmd.exe` was in fact not on unicode. Changed the locale to "Beta UTF8", restarted, reinstalled a nerdfont (it doesn't seem to persist), now `os.write()` prints the thumbs up on both `cmd.exe` and conemu! Interesting/weird behavior by ConEmu when running over a non-unicode `cmd.exe`

Comment: Great! Please feel encouraged to add your own answer documenting the above.